# fitExactly not working in r-436

Tags: sifr

I just recently upgraded to 436 from 419, and have found that fitExactly will no longer have any effect.

You can see an example here:

[(With 419)](http://alexgreendesign.com/2008/12/high-contrast-stylesheets/)
[(With 436)](http://alexgreendesign.com/2008/12/high-contrast-stylesheets/?sifr-436)

The javascript config is in the page head.

I checked the versions in between, and the latest it works with is 419.

I could adjust the width in the Javascript configuration, but then there would be a gap left on the side of the dropcap I'm using it on, and the fact that I'm integrating it with a Wordpress theme that automatically applies sifr (other than the one in the example), meaning that each can't be adjusted by changing the width or font size.

I would much prefer to use 436, especially due to there being less page shifting, so, is there a remedy?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Bot pages look exactly the same to me here. Safari 4.

Comment: Here are small images of what I see in Firefox 3, Safari 3, and Chrome:
http://alexgreendesign.com/?attachment_id=51 -419
http://alexgreendesign.com/?attachment_id=52 -436

and Safari 4:
http://alexgreendesign.com/?attachment_id=53 -419
http://alexgreendesign.com/?attachment_id=54 -436

Comment: Sorry, hadn't noticed that you only used sIFR for one character, was looking at the headlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare the width and height of the Flash movie on both pages, you'll see that it's the same. In other words, it looks like fitExactly works fine. I wouldn't know though why Flash is clipping the rendered text.

Just to test, could you open the r436 JavaScript file, search for '419' and replace by '436', and then use the r419 Flash movie? Perhaps that provides further clues.

Comment: I replaced 436 with 419 within the r436 file, using the 419 movie, and it no longer clips:
http://alexgreendesign.com/2008/12/high-contrast-stylesheets/?sifr-test

Comment: Odd. I'll have to look into this a bit closer then.